# argument passing to echo in PHP

Tags: php

here are i am providing some examples of echo

Example 1

```
echo 'The sum is ', 1 + 2; //works fine
```

Example 2

```
$x=true;
echo '$x is undefined value ' , ($x===true) ? 'NO' : 'Yes'; //Works fine
```

Example 3

```
function f($arg){
  return $arg;
}

echo 'hello ' , f('buddy'); //Works fine
```

Example 4 -

```
echo 'hello ' , if($a) { return "wowo"; } else { return "fine"; }; // generate parse error
```

Here is the point that all example working fine but example 4 its generating parse error.

my questions is that -
1. `language constructs` can be used for `echo` arguments ?
2. If **yes** `language constructs` can be used, how can we use `language constructs` for `echo` arguments ?
3. Only `functions` that return strings can be passed to `echo` arguments ?

Comment: Only functions can return values not the conditional constructs like `if...else, loops, switch...case` etc...

Comment: use function or try to use ternary oprators.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use language constructs to echo arguments or return values.
If else is a conditional statement which can be use to evaluate a value. using this you will be able to break the the logic into several pieces and evaluate the condition. the echo will work separately for an each statement. But if you return a value , it will be returned from function and not from the statement.
EX:

```
$value = "hello";
if($a) { $value.= "wowo"; } else { $value.= "fine"; }
echo $value;
```

in the other hand ternary operator is an **operator** that takes three arguments and performs an operation .